# How to properly handle generic types?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a custom function that will handles all my API response, but I don't know how to properly handle it.

This is my code

My Custom callback

```
interface ResponseCallback<T> {
    fun onSuccess(response: T)
    fun onError(code: Int, message: String)
}
```

This is how I call my request API

```
createRequest(getLogin(id), object : API.ResponseCallback<LoginResponse>{
    override fun onError(code: Int, message: String) {
    }

    override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
    }
})
```

and This is how I handle my request

```
fun createRequest(source: Observable<*>, callback: ResponseCallback<*>) {
    disposable.add(
        source.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { it ->
                    //
                    // callback.onSuccess(it)

                },
                {

                }
            )
    )
}
```

but my problem here is, the `callback.onSuccess()` parameter is `Nothing` and can't accept the `callback.onSuccess(it)`

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use [star projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) if you don't know the specific type parameter for a generic type. When you use these, the compiler will prevent you from doing unsafe things with the parameterized type. For example, you've seen that you can't pass in any parameter to `onSuccess`, since you've essentially told the compiler that you don't know what its type should be.

The fix then is to give your `createRequest` function a type parameter instead, and make both the `Observable` be of that type, as well as the callback that you wish to invoke:

```
fun <T> createRequest(source: Observable<T>, callback: ResponseCallback<T>) {
    ...
    callback.onSuccess(it) // works, since you're passing in a T to a method that requires a T
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi your answer really solve my problem, and since I'm very new in kotlin and experimenting some sort of custom function, I just also asking what should I do if I have a multiple response on my callback like `ResponseCallback<List<FirstClass>, List<SecondClass>, ThirdClass>`?

Comment: If you need a single function to take a `ResponseCallback` with those parameters, and they're not always of the same type, you could solve it the same way, by adding additional generic type parameters to your function.